# Outlook 2002 auto complete email adress deletion

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2002

I would like to delete a particular email address from Outlook's auto complete list. But I don't want to turn off all email address from the auto complete list. I tried to delete the email address when it displays and then it again pops up. Is there any other way to turn off this email address without using 3rd party software? I am using Outlook 2002.

Answer (score 1):

```
Create a new email message in Outlook.
Start typing the name or address you want to remove.
Use the down arrow key to highlight the desired (undesired) entry.
Press Del.
```

Reference: http://email.about.com/od/outlooktips/qt/et_del_autocomp.htm

Google Search: edit outlook autocomplete list

Comment: I tried this already and didnt work

Comment: Thank You. I created another wrong entry to make a drop down list to delete it. Cheers.

Comment: the easy way is to use a 3rd party free software, really easy and fast, NK2EDIT: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/outlook_nk2_edit.html